# HTML. Страница автоматически прокручивается вниз

Tags: html, прокрутка

Есть не очень известная CMS. При добавлении внизу главной страницы блока со ссылками, страница, при загрузке прокручивается в самый низ, к этому блоку. Как исправить подобное поведение? или хотя бы укажите направление, в котором копать

Comment: а у вас в ссылке точно нет якоря ? например в конце ссылки #footer

Comment: Якоря точно нету

Comment: ну значит вам надо проверить JS файлы на код скролинга , например найти scrollTop();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я могу предположить что у вас в конце страници находятся какие-то input "text" а на них повешены свойства focus или атрибуты autofocus

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Нужное направление указали) На странице скрипт, который focus на поле ввода вешал